# Package Orchard CMS module without source code

Tags: orchardcms, orchard-modules

when creating a new module with

```
package create
```

it creates it using source code *.cs files, so as a result nuget package does not contain binaries, the source only

Is it any parameter or option to precompile module, so instead of source files, it will precompile DLL?

The only option I found, is to open package file (which is ZIP file) and update content manually, but this is not best solution

Answer (score 1):

By design, Orchard modules are source code, to ensure that they are friendly to modification. If you want to deploy something without source code, it should be the whole site, not just one module. This can be done by building precompiled.